# Delphi & Lazarus both installed

Tags: delphi, lazarus

Just a quick question for those of you that know. Is it possible to have both Delphi (ver 7) and Lazarus installed at the same time. I want to make sure the Lazarus install will not interfere with my current Delphi install in ANY WAY. I would have asked this on the Lazarus fourms but thought I would get quicker reply here.

Anyway if you have both Delphi & Lazarus installed please tell me any problems you have encountered (if any) thanks.

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I currently have Delphi 5 and Lazarus both installed on my Windows 7 laptop. As near as I can tell they don't interfere with each other.

I don't really use Lazarus though, as I prefer Delphi 5 which is what I've used forever.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I was only interested in lazarus because of the cross platform capabilities so that is why I even considered it other than learning a new language such as python (which I may do anyway at a later date) but thanks again for the relpy.

Answer (score 4):

Lazarus does not interfere with any version of Delphi, they can live along very happily.

Comment: Thanks all for the replies I will give it a go then.

Answer (score 4):

The only interference is for commandline building, both projects have a make.exe file which are not the same.

This is easily solvable by not adding FPC to the path (removing it via control-panel system), and do a

```
set PATH=c:\fpc\2.5.1\bin\i386-win32;%PATH%
```

or wherever you installed as first line in your batch files.

I generally don't bother, but a previous employer we did a lot of cmdline building with dcc, and then it matters.

File associations are another, but already named. (but not such a big problem since the project extensions vary (.dpr vs .lpr, .dproj vs .lpi) )

Btw: Other development products (cygwin,mingw, and maybe even VS) have their own respective make.exe files and the same kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have Delphi 2006, Delphi 2010 and Lazarus installed. No problems at all. I am sure Delphi 7 will be the same. The only problem I can see could be the use of .pas extension in Lazarus. I mean because of association problems. But you can use a different extension for Lazarus (free pascal) source files. I think the installer asks you that.

Answer (score 0):

I have Lazarus "installed" on a USB drive.  It interferes with nothing whatsoever.  It is actually a checkout of the [Git repository](http://github.com/graemeg/) that mirrors the [SVN repository](http://svn.freepascal.org/svn/lazarus/trunk/).  I installed the latest stable FPC to `C:\FPC`, and then copied that folder to inside my lazarus source folder, e.g. `\lazarus\FPC\` (and then uninstalled the `C:\FPC` installation), and then whenever I like I build the latest lazarus like this:

```
X:\lazarus\> git fetch
[...fetch messages...]

X:\lazarus\> FPC\2.4.0\bin\i386-win32\make.exe clean all
[...compiler output messages...]

X:\lazarus\> startlazarus
[...IDE starts up...]
```

The main advantage of this is that if you find an IDE bug, the source is immediately available and you can make and [submit a patch](http://bugs.freepascal.org/my_view_page.php) instantly.